# Does ST monad have special compiler support?

Tags: haskell, monads, ghc

Does ST monad have special compiler support in GHC?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see the code for STRefs here: http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-STRef.html

It uses, clearly, `MutVar#` primitives. The `runST` code similarly uses the `RealWorld#` primitive and unboxed tuples. However, given simply IORefs and `unsafePerformIO` you could build your own `ST` monad with the same big-O properties, although probably less overall efficiency.

Comment: I don't see why it would be less efficient.  ST and IO have the exact same implementation, underneath ST's type trickery.  STRef = IORef, and runST = unsafePerformIO.

Comment: @Carl -- conceptually yes, implementationwise no. Take a look at `runST` vs `unsafePerformIO` -- the former is slightly more straightforward. (http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-ST.html and http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-IO.html) Also note that ST's monad instance uses unboxed tuples directly. You couldn't do that with a newtype wrapper around IO...

Answer (score 1):

Section 9 of [State in Haskell](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/state-lasc.ps.gz) might be of interest. I didn't read closely enough to tell whether what they described there actually requires compiler support, but it *did* sound like implementing some of the primitives in the compiler was the path of least resistance.